# How to format a string into XML on PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization

I made a string that contains XML (with tags and so on), but there is no alinea and break lines, so I think that it is better to format the xml as he has to be (with alinea and break lines)

So how can I convert a string into a beautifull xml in PHP?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SimpleXML`. Check it out here: [SimpleXML usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).
If you want to beautify your string you can use [SimpleXMLElement::asXML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php).

Comment: I think he's looking more for some kind of XML beautifier.

Comment: @Calin : Okay thanks but I want to send the XML beautifulled, not a HTML version of the XML... In fact I have to make a XML file so I think I have to make alineas and so on... isn't it?

Comment: Well the `asXML()` method returns a string if no file was specified. So I think you can use it for formatting your xml. If this is not what you want, can you please explain what you meant by "I have to make alineas and so on..."?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search took me to this PEAR package  [XML_Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Beautifier/redirected) which I think it's what you're asking for